# UCI- canada Application

Tags: tourist-visas, applications

I have an expired Canadian visiting visa and am about to apply for another one, Please how can I get my UCI ( Unique client identifier) number for the expired visa? Additionally, is it important to put the previous UCI number of my present application? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your UCI appears on any document from the Government of Canada. If you don’t have your UCI or any documents with it shown but want to fill out an application form you can leave the field for UCI (Client ID) blank. The latter implies it’s not important to include it.

Source: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=772&top=4